# Service Fabric (*.xml) Nodes and Attributes Documentation

Tags: azure-service-fabric

From where I can find the documentation which describes all the service fabric configuration XML nodes and attributes? And explains how they can be used?

XML I mean ServiceManifests, Settings, PublishProfiles, ApplicationParameters etc...

Or is there any?

Comment: Both answers provides good information in a distributed manner. That's understandable as we're living in distributed world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish profiles are described in [Publish an application to a remote cluster by using Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-publish-app-remote-cluster/).  Application parameters are described in [Manage application parameters for multiple environments](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration/).

Right now, ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd is the only doc that lists all the settings for ServiceManifest.xml and ApplicationManifest.xml. ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd is laid down by the Service Fabric SDK and Tools installer are described in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\schemas.  We're working to improve the descriptions in the .xsd file.  Several of our articles on azure.microsoft.com have examples of settings in the application and service manifest.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have also looked the xsd file, but descriptions have quite limited information. My opinion is that the configuration nodes and attributes cannot be considered as "well documented". Descriptions should somehow explain "what if or if not defined" and possible values / ranges at least... Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I agree, the descriptions are sparse right now.  We'll work to improve these and make them more useful.

Answer (score 0):

you could find some information here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration/

And some piece of information here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description/